# Combine columns on factor

Tags: r

I have data with factors `lang` and `alg` and I like to compare difference for selected `lang` pair between all `alg`:

```
> perf[perf$lang == "java", c("alg", "cpu")]
               alg   cpu
173    binarytrees 0.196
174 chameneosredux 0.404
175  fannkuchredux 0.648

> perf[perf$lang == "python3", c("alg", "cpu")]
               alg    cpu
246    binarytrees  0.972
248  fannkuchredux 13.752
249          fasta  1.152
```

For `binarytrees` I expect to get `0.196/0.972`, but for `chameneosredux` is `NA`, for `fannkuchredux` is `0.648/13.752`, for `fasta` is `NA`, ...

One way is to sort rows on `alg` but I don't understand how to inject rows with `NA` on missing factors (all factors available in `unique(perf$alg)`).

**UPDATE** Despite original question I think that I like to combine columns of two data frames into single data frame on same factor:

```
   binarytrees 0.196   0.972
chameneosredux 0.404      NA
         fasta    NA   1.152
 fannkuchredux 0.648  13.752
```

Comment: perhaps an answer to your original Q... `aggregate(cpu ~ alg, data=perf[perf$lang %in% c("java", "python3"),], function(x) x[1]/x[2])`

Comment: Otherwise, re your edit.. you can just reshape your data ..`reshape2::dcast(alg ~ lang, data=perf, value.var="cpu")`

Comment: @user20650 Get **errror**: *variable lengths differ (found for 'alg')* on real data. there are difference in row count in java/python3 slice ( for first suggestion).

Comment: Hmmm.. i dont know. it should still work for when there are non-matching number of rows / alg's between languages.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is essentially a `FULL OUTER JOIN` in SQL, which can be done with `base::merge` using `all = TRUE`.

Here is a comparable data set to demonstrate with:

```
Df <- data.frame(
    Lang = rep(LETTERS[1:5], rep(3, 5)),
    Alg = c(replicate(5, sample(letters[1:4], 3))),
    Cpu = rnorm(15),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Note that I'm using `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. I would suggest you convert your columns to `character` vectors as well; I don't see any need for using `factor`s here.

---

This is the `merge` operation in a light wrapper function, just to make the presentation a little cleaner:

```
compare <- function(x, y, data) {
    merge(x = data[data$Lang == x[1], 2:3],
          y = data[data$Lang == y[1], 2:3],
          by = "Alg", all = TRUE,
          suffixes = c(paste0(".", x[1]), 
                       paste0(".", y[1]))
    )
}
```

---

And here it is in use:

```
compare("A", "D", Df)
#  Alg      Cpu.A       Cpu.D
#1   a         NA -0.06520117
#2   b  1.0587151  0.08379303
#3   c -2.0390119          NA
#4   d -0.8574474  1.27865596

compare("A", "C", Df)
#  Alg      Cpu.A      Cpu.C
#1   b  1.0587151 -1.0230431
#2   c -2.0390119 -0.7691048
#3   d -0.8574474 -1.2421078
```

---

Regarding my comment, this can also be achieved using `sqldf`. `SQLite` does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`, but this shouldn't be too much of an issue if you are comfortable with SQL, as there are probably a dozen or so ways to work around that:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf(
    "select x.Alg 
        ,lhs.Cpu as 'Cpu.A'
        ,rhs.Cpu as 'Cpu.D'
     from (
        select distinct d.Alg
        from Df d
     ) x
     left join Df lhs on lhs.Alg = x.Alg and lhs.Lang = 'A'
     left join Df rhs on rhs.Alg = x.Alg and rhs.Lang = 'D'
     order by x.Alg"
)

#  Alg      Cpu.A       Cpu.D
#1   a         NA -0.06520117
#2   b  1.0587151  0.08379303
#3   c -2.0390119          NA
#4   d -0.8574474  1.27865596
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I already have another question which I formulate in SQL terms also! Sadly I haven't found  `SQL <=> R` cheatsheet. After a lot of SQL queries I think in SQL paradigms ((

Comment: The `data.table` and `dplyr` packages are useful for doing SQL-like operations on data in R, particularly aggregations. And if all else fails, the package `sqldf` allows you to execute SQL statements on `data.frame`s as if they were database tables. Unfortunately it does not support TSQL / MSSQL backends, but depending on your configuration (`SQLite, MySQL`, etc.) many ANSI SQL operations are supported.